# Saving model from three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Aside from the save tab in `three.js`, is it possible to save models from  `three.js` to a database then load them again?

Comment: If you have written code for this but you can't get it to work, then you have come to the right place, just add your code (or the relevant parts) to the question. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can export your model into Json three and save it in your server or less convenient save complete json as field in database.

Then you can load the

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
         loader.load(**PathJsonModel**,function ( obj ) {
            scene.add( obj );
            render();
         });
```

Comment: Actually I use Clara Io and export it to three json and I save as file and the path on database. and I load with ObjectLoader

Comment: @neoDev: please stick to English here, so everyone can join in the conversation. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer some time ago I proposed stackoveflow in Italian in area51. You can use google translate

Comment: @neoDev: excellent. If there is sufficient demand, I hope that is implemented. That doesn't change the language requirement here, though `:-)`.

Comment: How can you save it locally?

Comment: You can save it in text field in database or in a file in your file system project